# How do I set a variable to be a object's key so I can access an object dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use a variable to hold a key name for an object so I can do the below.

```
var obj = {name:'john', age: 8}
var holder
```

holder can be name or age so `obj.holder` can return `'john'` or `8` depending on what I set holder

How do I set a variable to be a object's key so I can access an object dynamically in javascript?

Comment: `var obj = {name:'john', age: 8};
obj['holder '] = 'holder ';
console.log(obj);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with  bracket notation when accessing the object properties:

```
var obj = {name:'john', age: 8}
var holder = 'name';

obj[holder]; // john

holder = 'age';
obj[holder]; // 8
```

Comment: Just try with... ... bracket notation :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {name:'john', age: 8};

var index = "john";
var holder = obj[index];
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".